# Moved host, got error PHP Notice: Use of undefined constant

Tags: php, undefined, constants, host

I just moved to new host
In this new host i always got error_log, even with this simple php file :

```
<?php define(Y,120); ?>
```

this is the error_log content:

```
[09-Apr-2015 18:42:09 UTC] PHP Notice: Use of undefined constant Y -
assumed 'Y' in /home/username/public_html/test.php on line 1
```

i can add single quote wrapping the Y like this to fix it

```
<?php define('Y',120); ?>
```

but there are a lot of code like that, it is better if i dont need to change the files,
but just change the hosting required, what is it actually? is it because using litespeed?

in old hosting there is cgi-fcgi information
http://freakimage.com/images/726cgi_fcgi.jpg

in new hosting is using litespeed
http://freakimage.com/images/118litespeed.jpg

Comment: You wrote bad code, and now it's erroring. Not much you can do other than fix it - I don't advise adjusting your error_reporting settings, it masks other errors (like this one!).

Comment: thank you for edited the post, just want do it, you are very fast, thanks

Answer (score 4):

This is wrong

```
<?php define(Y,120); ?>
```

first parameter of [define()](https://php.net/define) is string

thus it should be

```
<?php define('Y',120); ?>
```

The reason why it is so often seen without quotes is because people have turned off warnings and PHP is way too forgiving. In any case it is wrong to do it without quotes BEFORE defining the constant.

Of course you can just disable `E_NOTICE` errors with [error_reporting()](https://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) but it is bad practice. (As even serious errors are sometimes considered NOTICE by PHP).

Comment: but this php file & other scripts are working in my previous hosting, is it because litespeed in new hosting?

Comment: The level of error reporting can be defined in php.ini and thus was probably just different on your previous hosting. So in fact this "error" was there even on your previous hosting and was just ignored. The code still works as previously.

Comment: It's more likely that it's because you'd suppressed such notices in your previous hosting, so you weren't even aware of the problem.... nothing to do with litespeed

Comment: ok i tried the simple php file in another few hosting, that using cgi-fcgi 
there is no error_log

i tried in another few hosting, using litespeed
got error_log

can you tried the simple php file in your host guys? and check is it got error_log or not, if not why

Comment: The servers have different error reporting settings (check their php.ini), the behavior is still the same.